# Discord.py adding roles but getting the error role not found after trying both the name and the id of the role

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

All of this works just fine except for when it trys to apply the role it gives the error role not found even after trying two methods of calling the role.

```
  if rank == 'combatofficer':
    role = get(member.guild.roles, name="IRE Combat Officer")
    await member.add_roles(member, role)
    rank = 'Combat Officer'
  else:
    pass
```

I have also tried

```
  elif rank == 'juniorofficer':
    role = get(member.guild.roles, name="747688368153821244")
    await member.add_roles(member, role)
    rank = 'Junior Officer'
  else:
    pass
```

I cut out a good portion of the elif statements because I don't think they are necessary to bug finding this code. thanks

Comment: First of all putting the id in the name isnt going to do anything, have you tried printing out the role object and seeing if it actually returns some kind of role?

Comment: When I print it prints none in the console.

Comment: Then it actually does not find the role, check the name for case sensitive and if the bot has permission to see roles

Comment: Ive checked both cases and if the bot has access I even coded my bot to take the list of roles in the discord and print them to the console

Comment: still have not made any progress, it printed the role list and ive checked the names.

Comment: get the role by id then using `role = get(member.guild.roles, id=id_here)`